# How to Validate mac address & ipaddress in client side(using javascript) & server side(using c#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, asp.net-mvc

My team doing a project related to network using Asp.net MVC(c#).

I need to validate **mac address & ipaddress** in client side(using javascript) & server side(using c#) for a simple form entry. I didn't get a good solution for validating mac address & ip addresss.

I searched google for finding a good user interface for validating mac address by giving colon  after two number eg: "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX" by using Masked Input.Please give reference/guidance for implementing this. Any jquery plugin for implementing Masked Input.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get the addresses (ip,mac) server side the code below will help you:

```
public partial class RemoteClientInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{   

    public class NetUtils
        {
            //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366358(VS.85).aspx
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
            public static extern int SendARP(int DestIP, int SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref uint PhyAddrLen);

            private static System.Net.IPAddress GetIpAddress(string address)
            {
                System.Net.IPHostEntry hostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(address);
                if (hostEntry != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress in hostEntry.AddressList)
                    {
                        if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            return ipAddress;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            public static string GetMacAddress(string address)
            {
                System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = GetIpAddress(address);

                if (ipAddress != null)
                {
                    byte[] addressBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
                    byte[] macAddress = new byte[6];
                    uint macAddressLen = (uint)macAddress.Length;
                    if (SendARP(BitConverter.ToInt32(addressBytes, 0), 0, macAddress, ref macAddressLen) == 0)
                    {
                        return BitConverter.ToString(macAddress);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void GetClientInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string remoteIp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            string remoteMacAddr = NetUtils.GetMacAddress(remoteIp);
            this.InfoTextBox.Text = string.Format("ip=[{0}] mac=[{1}]", remoteIp, remoteMacAddr);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you tring to validate the format or the actual addresses?

if the former, try regualar expressions...

IP Address: 
    \b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b

Or take a look [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=982) regarding Mac Addresses

Comment: Use the regular expressions to validate the format using regular expressions (either client or server - probably best for both) then use the server to test connectivity to ip address via ping (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) and http://mycomponent.blogspot.com/2009/05/get-mac-address-in-c-from-ip.html if the MAC in question relates to the IP